# CakePHP calling a view of a different class to render with the main class view

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm confused how you render a view that belongs to one class inside of another class. So I have a HomeController that wants to call my StudentsController index function. I'm not understand how CakePHP does this.

Answer (score 4):

You usually don't have to.
If controller need to share part of another view, you should extract that into a shared element. This way they can easily use the same view part.

If you really have to you can use an absolute syntax for render() to render other controllers' views. But I would not recommend that.

```
$this->render('/SomeController/action');
```

Comment: Why don't you recommend using path relative to `/app/View` folder? Also, [link to documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render) where this usage is mentioned.

Comment: That can create dependencies inside the app, which you might not always be aware off. but it ain't that big of a deal either. I usually just prefer to work with elements here inside the views.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, just place the code in your HomeController within your action -

```
$this->render('/Students/index');
```

Comment: If you found this as ur answer then choose it as ur answer.

Comment: Tip: creating a (less complete) copy of an existing answer is not likely to get you an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

what is your purpose?
maybe need to call all the action, because you need the variables for that view.

And for that you can use:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Students', 'action' => 'index'));
```